# Matlab VPA slowness

Tags: matlab

I am writing a program to decrypt RSA-encrypted messages by factorising the prime number and I want to test it on some long primes so I need to use Variable Precision Arithmetic, but for some reason even when I use small numbers it is significantly slower when I use VPA with a small number of digits. What is going on?

Comment: How much slower is it? How big is the test? Can you share some of the code with us?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser About 100 times slower... I have tried it with just a simple loop and have the same issue e.g.
`m=1;
for i=1:d
    m=mod(vpa(m*c),n);
end`

Comment: Hm, it looks like Matlab uses 16 digits by default in normal calculations and 32 by default in VPA. How does `vpa(m*c, 16)` compare?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I even tried `vpa(m*c,2)` where $m*c$ is no more than 2 digits and it takes about 100 times longer than normal. Very strange.